# Is Lord Chaitanya and Nityananda Mahapravu both are same person?

Tags: krishna, vishnu, chaitanya

Is Lord Chaitanya and Nityananda Mahapravu both are same person or they are different avatar?

Comment: They are different.Lord chaitanya Mahaprabhu is regarded as incarnation of Krishna while Nityanand Prabhu regarded as incarnation of Balaram by Gaudiya Vaishnav(of which ISKCON is a part).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, They are two different person with nityananda mahaprabhu being senior to chaitanya Mahaprabhu.
[http://gaudiyahistory.iskcondesiretree.com/lord-nityananda-prabhu/](http://Help%20Link)

Comment: Thanks for your response but the URL is not opening. Could you please check and confirm the url? @Amu